# Retrieving a trusted client token within a Keycloak addon (SPI)

Tags: client, token, keycloak, add-on, trusted

As part of our effort to be GDPR compliant, I’m trying to extend our Keycloak server with some custom functionality, to be triggered when a user is removed:

- sending a confirmation message to a Slack channel
- sending a HTTP request to another service we built, to delete any assets that user might have created there

The first one was easy. It's implemented as a SPI event listener, following [this example](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/callback-hook-on-user-creation/5259/15):

```
@Override
public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {
    keycloakSessionFactory.register(
        (event) -> {
            // the user is available via event.getUser()
            if (event instanceof UserModel.UserRemovedEvent){
                userRemovedMessageHandler.handleUserRemoveEvent(session, (UserRemovedEvent) event);
                LOG.debug("User removed event happened for user: " + ((UserRemovedEvent) event).getUser().getId());
            }
        });
}
```

But I'm stuck on the second task (sending the HTTP request). The other service is set up to require a `trusted client token`, using a designated `Keycloak Client` and `scope`. The equivalent POST request to `auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token` is done with these parameters:

```
grant_type: password
username: {user that is about to be deleted}
password: {user password}
client_id: {the specific client}
client_secret: {that client's secret}
scope: usersets
```

I can’t find out how to do that from within the SPI code. I can retrieve a regular Access Token (as described in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63742225/how-to-obtain-an-access-token-within-a-keycloak-spi)):

```
private String getAccessToken(KeycloakSession session, UserModel deleteUser) {
    KeycloakContext keycloakContext = session.getContext();
    AccessToken token = new AccessToken();
    token.subject(deleteUser.getId());
    token.issuer(Urls.realmIssuer(keycloakContext.getUri().getBaseUri(), keycloakContext.getRealm().getName()));
    token.issuedNow();
    token.expiration((int) (token.getIat() + 60L)); //Lifetime of 60 seconds
    KeyWrapper key = session.keys().getActiveKey(keycloakContext.getRealm(), KeyUse.SIG, "RS256");
    return new JWSBuilder().kid(key.getKid()).type("JWT").jsonContent(token).sign(
        new AsymmetricSignatureSignerContext(key));
}
```

but that's *not* the token I need. In order to retrieve the required *trusted client token* I’d need the internal Keycloak / SPI-equivalent of the above POST request, but I can’t figure out how to do that or where to look.

Besides, I'm not sure if it is even possible to retrieve a trusted client token for a user that is in the process of being deleted. In other words, I don’t know if the UserRemovedEvent is fired before, during or after the user is actually deleted, or if Keycloak waits until any custom EventHandlers have finished running.

*(In order to figure that out, I'll try if it is possible to retrieve that token using a regular http POST request from *within the add-on code*, but I have no idea if it's possible to connect to Keycloak like that from inside. I'll update the question if that works.)*

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestion!

*(I also asked this in the Keycloak discourse group [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/retrieving-a-trusted-client-token-within-a-custom-spi/13178) but it looks as if it will remain unanswered there)*

Comment: would using grant client_credentials help? you can get a client token and invoke your API - this would also make more sense rather than using a deleted user's token

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that.